# Exporting a .sql database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, import, phpmyadmin, export

When exporting a database from phpMyAdmin, what option should I select?

> Quick - display only the minimal options

or

> Custom - display all possible options

I need to Import this database back into another phpMyAdmin of my local server `MAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to export database that is to be used in another computer's local server. then it's ok to select  "Quick"